# Function overloads with optional parameters

Tags: typescript

I am experimenting with function overloads in Typescript and I am getting the following error:

> Error:(2, 5) TS2394: Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.

I don't understand how to resolve this error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
create(key: string | TextKeys, reKey: string | TextKeys, params?: ObjectLiteral<string>, subkeys?: { [key: string]: string }, selector?: Selector): Either<EError, (AOutput | ROutput)[]>;
create(key: string | TextKeys, params?: ObjectLiteral<string>, subkeys?: { [key: string]: string }, selector?: Selector): Either<EError, AOutput>;
create(key: string | TextKeys, reKey?: string | TextKeys, params?: ObjectLiteral<string>, subkeys?: { [key: string]: string }, selector: Selector = selectRandom) {
    const output: Either<EError, AOutput> = this.createAOutputs(key, params, subkeys).map(selector);
    if (reKey !== undefined) {
        return List.fromArray([output, this.createROutputs(reKey, params, subkeys)]).sequenceEither<EError, AOutput | ROutput>().map(arr => _.flatten(arr.toArray())) as Either<EError, (AOutput | ROutput)[]>;
    } else {
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how to resolve this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Your last function signature MUST work for every possible overload. A quick hack to show what will work:

```
create(key: string | TextKeys, reKey: string | TextKeys, params?: ObjectLiteral<string>, subkeys?: { [key: string]: string }, selector?: Selector): Either<EError, (AOutput | ROutput)[]>;
create(key: string | TextKeys, params?: ObjectLiteral<string>, subkeys?: { [key: string]: string }, selector?: Selector): Either<EError, AOutput>;
create(...iWorkWithAllOptions:any[]) { // NOTICE 
    // implement
}
```

Comment: But then I’d lose type checking on the implementation. Technically my function signature works for the above two overloads.

Comment: It is still type safe for *caller*. The implementation loses type safety, but that said, your function body will *always* need to cater for *all* the overload cases.

Comment: Is there a way to make it cater to the second overload case and keep type safety in the implementation? It's worth noting that `TextKeys` does fit the type of `ObjectLiteral<string>`. Do you think that's causing the issue?